# Create JSON object with single or multiple value parameters and execute REST API request

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I've JSON Payload as below:

```
{
  "Size": "100",
  "ApplicationSource": "AMAZON",
  "SearchData": [
   {
     "key": "orderID",
     "value": ["23434332", "45654456",...]  
   },
   {
     "key": "orderGroupCode",
     "value": "101"
    }
  ]
}
```

The `value` for `orderID` key in `SearchData` element can be **single value** or **multiple values** and are dynamic like this:

```
"value": "23434332"
or
"value": ["23434332", "45654456","5545645"]
```

How to create JSON object and parse and Execute RestClient request in C#.

Comment: asked already multiple times ... you need create custom converter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18994685/how-to-handle-both-a-single-item-and-an-array-for-the-same-property-using-json-n)

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Comment: What JSON serializer or framework are you using?  Assuming you are using [tag:json.net] then [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182) is the correct duplicate.  But if you're not using Json.NET then please let us know what you are using.